# '-' In v-bind:style / Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I cant understand how to make CSS code into v-bind:style with symbol '-'.
If i try to do something like that:

```
<DIV style="width:100px;height: 100px;background-color: red;cursor: pointer;" v-bind:style="{ margin-left: margin + 'px'}"></DIV>
```

I get:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token '-' in
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1) of Vue: "You can use either camelCase or kebab-case (use quotes with kebab-case) for the CSS property names"

So you'd need to change the `margin-left` to either `marginLeft` OR `'margin-left'` to get it to work as intended.

Your code would then become:

```
<div style="width:100px;height: 100px;background-color: red;cursor: pointer;" 
     v-bind:style="{ 'margin-left': margin + 'px'}">
     ...
</div>
```

OR

```
<div style="width:100px;height: 100px;background-color: red;cursor: pointer;" 
     v-bind:style="{ marginLeft: margin + 'px'}">
    ...
</div>
```

Hope this helps!